# How to draw in higher bit depth?

Tags: c#, winforms, bitmap

I'd like to either draw an image with a bit depth of 48 (16 bits per channel) to the screen, or manually draw pixels with the same bit depth (or 16-bit grayscale, if need be). I've created an empty Bitmap with the right bit depth like this:

```
Bitmap orig = new Bitmap("../../grat1.png");
Bitmap clone = new Bitmap(1804, 1804, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format48bppRgb);
```

And then created a Graphics from the Bitmap like this:

```
using (Graphics gr = Graphics.FromImage(clone))
{
}
```

But while grat1.png has a bit depth of 48, when I load it into orig and draw it to gr it defaults to a 32bpp PixelFormat. I've also tried to individually modify the pixels of clone using SetPixel, but I can't seem to do it without being limited to the usual 0-255 (8 bits per channel) range. Is it possible to render graphics with a higher bit depth in C#?

Comment: Not all __defined__ formats are __supported__, unfortunately..